# Splitting source document in Sphinx (i.e. managing files hierarchy)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

What is the correct way, if any, of splitting a source document in Sphinx?

I have a large file, let's call it `file1.rst`, the structure of which is like this:

```
Section 1
*********

Subsection 1
============

Subsection 2
============

Subsection 3
============
```

Each subsection is very long, and the source file has become unmanageable. I would like to put each subsection in a different source file.

I tried with the `include` directive:

```
Section 1
*********
.. include:: subsection1.rst
.. include:: subsection2.rst
.. include:: subsection3.rst
```

But it's issuing warnings that labels in subsection1.rst are duplicated in section1.rst (not true, the label is only in the sub-document).

Alternatively, is there any possibility to change the hierarchy in the TOC directive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm answering my own question (shame!) because I finally understood what I was getting wrong.

**The TOC, table of contents directive can be used *multiple* times.** This will result in the hierarchical structure that I was looking for.

I hope this can be of help for those who, like me, thought that there can be one TOC only.

Comment: You did not tell just *how* you placed the multiple TOC directives to get exactly the same structure, so the table of contents and the sidebar remained the same.

Comment: Each parent file can have a toc, which points to the children. That way you can have a full tree, as deep as you like. Does that make sense?

Comment: What's a parent file? You don't have includes, do you?

Comment: Do you mean a parent file, just like `index.rst`, in a subdirectory, along with the `subsection*.rst` files?

Comment: I suppose you did something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310950/collapse-all-glob-discovered-files-into-one-toc-entry) :)