# Collapse all :glob:-discovered files into one TOC entry

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I've got something like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
   :hidden:
   :glob:

   docs
   frontend
   backend
   tools/*
```

I'd like all the documents found in the `tools` directory to collapse into one expandable **sidebar** TOC entry. Should be possible, but I can't find a clue.

I use `sphinx_rtd_theme`.

To put it another way: suppose I have a very long document like this (`tools.rst`):

```
Section 1
*********

Subsection 1
============

Subsection 2
============

Subsection 3
============
```

How am I supposed to split it by the subsection and preserve the document structure, without resorting to includes, which don't sit well with Sphinx anyway.

Comment: Where is your "very long document"? Is it `tools/example.rst`? Are you saying that the subsections do not appear in the sidebar navigation? Did you try `:maxdepth: 3`?

Comment: No. I've got a very long `tools.rst` with one section heading in my `source` directory; I'd like to split it into `source/tools` *and* preserve the structure (a single section heading). I did not manage it.

Comment: Neither `tools.rst` nor `tools` is in the `toctree`. That is why it does not appear in the navigation. You must have one of them in the `toctree` listing for it to appear.

Comment: Oh, It's just the edited `index.rst`. Of course, `tools.rst` initially was present in the `index.rst`. I did not manage to split and move it into `source/tools` *and* preserve the appearance and hierarchy. The Section no longer is root to Subsections. Include directives work, by the way, but they are ugly and cumbersome.

Comment: Please update your question with the current state of your files and what problem you face with their current state. I cannot follow you at all.

Comment: Sorry. I discovered what I wanted, at last, and made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source/index.rst`:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
   :glob:

   tools/_tools
   docs
   frontend
   backend
   tmp/*
```

Old `source/tools/_tools.rst`:

```
Notes on tools
**************

.. include:: black.rst
.. include:: docker.rst
.. include:: git_hooks.rst
.. include:: github_webhooks.rst
.. include:: mypy.rst
.. include:: pipm.rst
.. include:: poetry.rst
.. include:: sphinx.rst
.. include:: uvicorn.rst
```

New `source/tools/_tools.rst`:

```
Notes on tools
**************

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :glob:

   *
```

The new one renders exactly like the old one, and is more versatile an a lot cleaner.